# How to rerun the process if it dies - Linux

Tags: linux, shell, embedded, embedded-linux

Can any one let me know how to re-run the process automatically again if it gets dies. Below is my code which i have tired but it is giving me an  error :

**Edited Code :**

```
commandpid=`$busyboxValue pidof command`
echo ${commandpid} > /sdcard/CommandProcess.txt
if [ $commandpid -gt 0 ]
then
    echo -16 > /proc/$commandpid/oom_adj
    echo -1000 > /proc/$commandpid/oom_score_adj
fi

while [ true ]
do
    echo "PID $commandpid"
    if [ ps -p $commandpid > /dev/null ]
    then
        echo "[$(date)] :Process is already running with PID $commandpid"
    else
        echo "[$(date)] :Process is not running"
        /data/local/command 1200 &
        commandpid=`$busyboxValue pidof command`
        echo ${commandpid} > /sdcard/CommandProcess.txt
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

I have updated the code but still with the above code multiple process id i am getting. Dose it mean my else part code is keep executing? If yes the what changes i need to do to stop it?

Can please any one help me ?

Answer (score 3):

To repeatedly run a command, regardless of exit status:

```
while :; do command; done
```

To repeatedly run a command *until* a successful exit:

```
until command; do :; done
```